# Creating .sln/vcproj files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, project, visual-studio-express

I would like to write a program or script that would generate .vcproj and .sln files for me. I currently have a lot of settings/configurations that I need to set for every .vcproj I create and I have seen people be able to generate these files some how, although I can not find a good resource through msdn or bing to do so. Could someone please post a link to a resource or perhaps a guide on how to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you can post what changed you want. I don't think all of the format is documented and I don't think its easy either

Comment: Are the settings unique to each project?  Are they dynamic?  If not, just put them in an imported .props file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate .sln/.vcproj with MSVS object model. It can be macros or add-in. This sample is a macros to generate .sln/.vcproj.

```
Sub SlnVcprojGenerator()
    Dim sln As Solution
    Dim prj As Project
    sln = DTE.Solution
    sln.Create("C:\test", "new_sln.sln")
    prj = sln.AddFromTemplate("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\VCWizards\default.vcproj", "c:\test", "new_prj", True)
    sln.SaveAs("C:\test\new_sln.sln")
End Sub
```

Comment: In addition to the DTE object model, there is a new approach using the MSBuild assemblies as well that is worth a look.  Check out Microsoft.Build.dll in Framework v4.0, specifically the Microsoft.Build.Construction namespace.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've seen/used, CMake is pretty useful for generating project/solution files.

Comment: CMake does a great job. However, we should point out that CMake created projects cannot be transferred to other workstations. This means you have to use CMake as build systems for all developers. But I suggest to do exactly this!

Comment: And devs need to remember to update project settings in the CMake script, not just in Visual Studio :P

Answer (score 1):

We create csproj files from script, but we did it just by inspecting the xml and copying.  We do get warnings each time we open the manually generated project files though.  We can get around that by adding entries to a registry entry somewhere.

I suppose with enough work you could mimic whatever portion of the csproj/vcproj that makes it "official".

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create project or item templates? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188697.aspx

You can even export a template from a given project, like explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx. Though this option is actually not available yet for VC++ in VS, there is an add-on, built by the Visual Studio Platform Team, available on the Visual Studio Gallery http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/57320b20-34a2-42e4-b97e-e615c71aca24/. It enables the same functionality for VC++.